# Convert a C project to Library to use in QT

Tags: c, linux, qt, shared-libraries

I have a C project which spits out an executable. I want to convert that project into a library which I want to use in my QT C++ application.

I am hitting a wall. Can someone provide me any information on it?

So I have been looking at https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application#Creating_a_static_library

I created a no-qt project to compile and it generates a `.a` file.
Here is my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    libmnl/dhcp/dhcpclient.c \
    libmnl/dhcp/dhcpmsg.c \
    libmnl/dhcp/packet.c \
    libmnl/attr.c \
    libmnl/callback.c \
    libmnl/ifutils.c \
    libmnl/nlmsg.c \
    libmnl/socket.c \
    atc.c \
    atchannel.c \
    at_tok.c \
    device.c \
    GobiNetCM.c \
    mbim-cm.c \
    MPQMUX.c \
    qmap_bridge_mode.c \
    QMIThread.c \
    QmiWwanCM.c \
    udhcpc_netlink.c \
    util.c

HEADERS += \
    libmnl/dhcp/dhcp.h \
    libmnl/dhcp/dhcpmsg.h \
    libmnl/dhcp/packet.h \
    libmnl/ifutils.h \
    libmnl/libmnl.h \
    atchannel.h \
    at_tok.h \
    MPQMUX.h \
    QMIThread.h \
    util.h

DISTFILES +=


QMAKE_CFLAGS += -Wall #-s
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lpthread -ldl -lrt

LIBS += -pthread
```

My understanding tells me that my C project spits out an executable instead I want it to spit out a library and a header

Which I could then add it to my QT project

Comment: "I am hitting a wall. Can someone provide me any information on it?" How are we supposed to help you in any way, if you give zero detail about your project?

Comment: @lulle What information do you need? Do you want me to add my make file to this question or do you want to see my project. It c project with makefile that I am building on a linux system with a main.c and I want to convert that into library so that I can use add it to my QT project. I literally don't know what information you want? Can you spell it out and I can add those info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application

Note that I have C++ libraries that I include in my Qt projects and don't have to do anything special at all. I just produce libFOO.a and then edit my Qt projects .pro file to add -L and -lFOO. Here is a cut & paste from one such project.

```
LIBS += -L../MyLib/lib -lMyLib
```

You might also have to add something like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../MyLib/src
```

Notice there's no -I on this.

Comment: I have been looking into it... Let me add my more info on my question. Now that I know what to add.

Comment: just added more information. Hopefully that can add some perspective

Comment: I hand-produce my own Makefiles for my libraries, so I'm not sure the magical incantation to get it to produce a library. But if you create a new project and tell it to be a library instead of an app, you can then look at what it produces and fiddle your original project's .pro file. My coworkers don't use Qt as their IDE, so we use the GNU G++ toolstack as a common denominator.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct. Because basically I did create a static library. I was just too slow to understand that all I had to do was add the static library as an external library to my project